# How many types of continuity are there?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Currently I'm familiar with continuity on the reals and uniform continuity, which releases the dependency of $\delta$ on $a$, all from a Calculus perspective.

What other types of continuities are there?

Comment: Just an example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Comment: There is e,g, [Holder continuoous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) and [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).  Moving away from real numbers - in topology there is a [much more general definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces).

Comment: Well over $100$ types can be found if you scrutinize the following books: [**Real Functions**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/3540160582) by Brian S. Thomson, [**Theory of Differentiation**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0471253871) by Krishna M. Garg, [**Real Functions − Current Topics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3540600086) by Vasile Ene, and [**Symmetric Properties of Real Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824792300) by Brian S. Thomson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many types of continuity and most of them are subsumed under topology where we give the domain and codomain a certain topology and a fixed general notion of continuity always applies.
Here the topologies are usually given by open sets, or equivalently by nets (which generalise sequences).

One form of continuity that does not fall into this category is uniform continuity and which requires uniform spaces and which has three standard definitions - one of them is by entourages.

Another kind of continuity that also does not fall into this category, is completeness which requires Cauchy sequences. This is axiomatised by Cauchy spaces.

Moreover, there are more general notions of topology; for example, proximity and pseudo-topological spaces. The former generalises uniform spaces, as it is equivalent to allowing more than one uniformity in a space (upto a class worth) and the latter generalises topological spaces in its definition by nets, here it uses ultranets or ultrafilters.